How to use Twitch API with a browser extension to show a notification when a specific user is streaming?
I'm trying to make a browser extension (currently trying to make it for Google Chrome, will try for Firefox and other later) that send a notification when a specific streamer is streaming. I've already done the notification part but I have two problems on my hands

Is using Twitch API: I've searched a bit and what I've understood is that I need to make the user authorize the Twitch extension I was forced to create so I can have a Oauth Token from them and my client-id and secret from the twitch extension. Is that really the case or there is a workaround? Because some people may not want to link their twitch account to the extension for that and could be seen as a phishing attempt.

I'm using chrome.alarms for checking every x minutes if the user is streaming but I read on Google Chrome dev website that sometime closing the brower or other thing can reset/delete the alarm and I would like to know how to prevent that ?


Currently the small work around that I've found for the API problem is fetching the channel link of the user and searching for the isBroadcasting string to check if they are streaming, but I know that using this method is seen as a bad practice and would like to use the API, since then it would be easier to get the stream title, game name, game boxart etc
Here is my current code for getting if the user is streaming:
async function checkIfLive(username) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`https://twitch.tv/${username}`);
        const sourceCode = await response.text();

        if (sourceCode.includes("isLiveBroadcast")) {
            showNotification({ message: "Is streaming", title: "Debug" });
        }
        else {
            showNotification({ message: "Is not streaming", title: "Debug" });
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        showNotification({ message: "Error", title: "Debug" });
    }

}

let username = "<TWITCH_USERNAME>";
checkIfLive(username);


Your current workaround (periodic fetching) looks like the best solution to me as it doesn't require an API token, so why specifically do you think it's bad? Which of the info you want to extract is not present in html? Note that you can parse it properly in the offscreen document.

@woxxom I see it as bad because in my point of view it's like a "dirty" way to get the information I need and may be returning (for example) not the information I would want if twitch change something in their design etc., like try to get the game box art and getting something else instead.
If the helix API didn't ask for each user to authorize the app (like wth twitch, for an extension like mine it's useless) I would greatly use the API because of the simple JSON return it gives

Indeed, there is such a problem, but sites usually don't change much if I use flexible selectors.

Would you be able to tell me how to get the stream title, game name and game box-art with a method similar to the one I used for checking if streaming?

You can probably reuse the native API key if you embed twitch.tv in an iframe inside the offscreen document, so your content script for the MAIN world could see the key as a global variable. The content script should be declared with all_frames:true and it should check window!==top && location.ancestorOrigins[0].startsWith('chrome-extension://')
